You roll three dice. What is the probability that two of these dice sum to an even number?

You roll three dice. What is the probability that two of these dice sum to an even number?

Let 'E' be the event of rolling an even number and 'O' be the event of rolling an odd number.
Since the events OOO, EOO, OEO, OOE, EOE, EEO, OEE, and EEE, all satisfy the condition that two of these dice sum to an even. and each of these events happen in 3*3*3 ways and there are 8 such events,
Is the Probability = 216/216 = 1?

Yeah, the answer is actually $1$! You can make the entire question non-probabilistic too : roll three dice, prove that there are two faces whose sum must be even. This can then be given a solution using the pigeonhole principle, instead of going case by case.

So my approach is right? And 1 is the answer?

Yes, the answer is correct.
